# PDFBox: How to print pdf with specified printer?

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdfbox

**I want to use PDFBox for printing PDF files** created by iText. I have tried this successfully with PDDocument class and its method print(). You can find documentation here: http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/.

(I am using this code:)

```
public static void printPDF(String fileName)
        throws IOException, PrinterException {
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(fileName);
    doc.print();
}
```

The method print() works great, but **there is one problem: When I need to print multiple files, the method asks me to select printer for each one of documents..**

**Is there any way how to set printer only once?**

For printer selection I can use this code for example:

```
public static PrintService choosePrinter() {
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    if(printJob.printDialog()) {
        return printJob.getPrintService();          
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

---

### Solution:

```
public static PrintService choosePrinter() {
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    if(printJob.printDialog()) {
        return printJob.getPrintService();          
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

public static void printPDF(String fileName, PrintService printer)
        throws IOException, PrinterException {
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPrintService(printer);
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(fileName);
    doc.silentPrint(job);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`PDDocument` also offers other print methods than the parameterless `print()`:

```
public void print(PrinterJob printJob) throws PrinterException;
public void silentPrint() throws PrinterException;
public void silentPrint(PrinterJob printJob) throws PrinterException;
```

The `silentPrint` methods don't show the dialog.

You may get what you want by first selecting a printer and then call `silentPrint` with `PrinterJob` instances initialized accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was blind.

Comment: Can you please show example of the silentPrint(). Nobody explained about the silentPrint.

Comment: @YumYumYum which PdfBox version do you use? Some 1.8.x version or the current 2.0.0 release candidate? The whole API has changed considerably...

Comment: Sir, here is my 2.0.0 code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15155477/, i have to print it silent mode without any popup. can you please advise kindly ?

Comment: As mentioned above, the API has changed considerably in 2.0.0. I'll have to search before I can say anything substantial. You should consider asking an actual stack overflow question on this matter, referring to this one and asking how to do the same with PdfBox 2.0.0.

Answer (score 3):

```
 import java.awt.print.PrinterException;

 import java.io.IOException;

 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

 public class Print {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, PrinterException
{
    PDDocument pdf=PDDocument.load("d:\\filename.pdf");
            pdf.print();
}

}
```

use the above code to print pdf using apache Pdfbox

**EDIT: version 2.0.0**

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.printing.PDFPageable;

public class JPrint {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, PrinterException {
    String filename;
    filename = "C:\\pdf.pdf";

    try {
      PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(new File(filename));
      PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
      job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(pdf));
      job.print();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what the OP wrote he did and which did not work in a satisfying manner.

Comment: How do i select specific printer before pdf.print(); ?

Answer (score 2):

```java
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "\\pdf.pdf"));  //read pdf file.
String printerNameDesired = "VENDOR THERMAL PRINTER";

javax.print.PrintService[] service = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices(); 
DocPrintJob docPrintJob = null;

int count = service.length;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (service[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(printerNameDesired)) {
        docPrintJob = service[i].createPrintJob();
        i = count;
    }
}

PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
pjob.setPrintService(docPrintJob.getPrintService());
pjob.setJobName("job");
doc.silentPrint(pjob);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **setPrintService() method** on the **PrinterJob** Object.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("C:/temp/example.pdf"));

    PrintService myPrintService = findPrintService("My Windows printer Name");

    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));
    job.setPrintService(myPrintService);
    job.print();

}

private static PrintService findPrintService(String printerName) {
    PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
    for (PrintService printService : printServices) {
        if (printService.getName().trim().equals(printerName)) {
            return printService;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. But is a old version pdfbox. The new version not support .load and .silentprint

```
public static void print(String nomImpresora, int cantVia) throws Exception {

    String aux;
    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
    int selectedService = -1;
    if (nomImpresora != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
                aux = services[i].getName();
                Log.addLog(Log.tipoMensaje.ErrorGenerico, "El valor de aux: " + aux + ".");
                if (services[i].getName().toUpperCase().contains(nomImpresora.toUpperCase())) {
                     /*If the service is named as what we are querying we select it */
                    selectedService = i;
                }
            }
        }

    if (selectedService == -1) {
        new Exception("Impresora no encontrada " + nomImpresora);
    }

    File fileToPrint = new File(rutaNombreArchivo);
    PDDocument load = PDDocument.load(fileToPrint.toString());       

    try {
        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        Log.addLog(Log.tipoMensaje.ErrorSQL, "selected service" + selectedService);
        printJob.setPrintService(services[selectedService]);
        printJob.setJobName(fileToPrint.getName());

        final HashPrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

        printJob.print(printRequestAttributes);
        for (int i = 1; i <= cantVia; i++) {
             load.silentPrint(printJob);
        } 
    } catch (final PrinterException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
       if (load != null) {
           load.close();
    }
}


}
```