# PDF printing with PDBOX , Page size decrease

Tags: pdf, printing, pdfbox

I want to print pdf file generated by itext. I also use PDFBox for this. At this page

[PDFBox: How to print pdf with specified printer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636622/pdfbox-how-to-print-pdf-with-specified-printer)

everything is explained, but I am having problem about page size. Original size of pdf file is 10x150 mm (3,93x5,9 inch). When I run the code the file is printed but not with its original size. My pdf file is printed at the noth-west of the page with nearly %70 decreased size.

Here is my code for this

```
public class LabelPrinter {

public LabelPrinter() {
}

public static PrintService getNamedPrinter(String name, PrintRequestAttributeSet attrs) {
PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, attrs);
if (services.length > 0) {
  if (name == null)
    return services[0];
  else {
    for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
      if (services[i].getName().equals(name))
        return services[i];
    }
  }
}
return null;
 }



public static void printLabel(String fileName,String printerName) throws FileNotFoundException, PrintException, IOException, PrinterException{


PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PrintService myService=getNamedPrinter(printerName, null);
if(myService!=null){

job.setPrintService(myService);
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(fileName);
doc.print(job);
}
else{
    System.out.println("printer not found");
}


}
```

}

I hope I could explain enough. (Accept my appologies for my bad English)