# Print a in memory pdf in Java

Tags: java, printing

I am developing a module where i am supposed to print documents from the server. Following are the requirements :

1. the module should be able to print a pdf from a url, with & without saving
2. the module should be able to accept page numbers as parameters and only print/save those page numbers.
3. the module should be able to accept the printer name as a parameter and use only that printer

Is there any library available for this? How should i go about implementing this?

Comment: "*Is there any library available for this?*" - [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) . I was able to load the PDF into a PDDocument object like this :

```
PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(new URL(download_pdf_from).openStream());
```

Splitting the document was as easy as :

```
Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
List<PDDocument> splittedDocuments = splitter.split(pdf);
```

Now, to get a reference to any particular page:

```
splittedDocuments.get(pageNo);
```

Saving the entire document or even a given page number :

```
pdf.save(path); //saving the entire document to device
splittedDocuments.get(pageNo).save(path); //saving a particular page number to device
```

For the printing part, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636622/pdfbox-how-to-print-pdf-with-specified-printer) answer helped me.