# How to generate pdf file and give command to print that generated file in android

Tags: android

i need to generate a pdf file and give print that file how do i  do it in android  i used the dependency

```
 implementation 'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.0-RC3'
```

and i code pdf Adapter as follows

```
public class PdfCreateAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PdfCreateAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<PDFModel> pdfModels;

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_pdf_creation, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PDFModel model = pdfModels.get(position);
        if (model != null) {
            if (model.isReceived()) {
                holder.mReceivedTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.mReceivedTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            holder.mPriceTV.setText(model.getPrice());
            holder.mNameTV.setText(model.getName());
            int ratingDrawable = getRatingImage(model.getRating());
            holder.mRateIM.setImageResource(ratingDrawable);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pdfModels.size();
    }

    /**
     * This is set from PDFCreateByXML class
     * This is my own model. This model have to set data from api
     *
     * @param pdfModels
     */
    public void setListData(List<PDFModel> pdfModels) {
        this.pdfModels = pdfModels;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * Set rating image
     *
     * @param rating this is getting from api and set to image by rate point
     * @return
     */
    private int getRatingImage(float rating) {
        int image = 0;
        if (rating == 0f) {
            image = R.drawable.pdf_star_1;
        } else if (rating == 0.5f) {
            image = R.drawable.pdf_half_star_2;
        } else if (rating == 1f) {
            image = R.drawable.pdf_star_2;
        } else if (rating == 1.5f) {
            image = R.drawable.pdf_half_star_3;
        } else if (rating == 2f) {
            image = R.drawable.pdf_star_3;
        } else if (rating == 2.5f) {
            image = R.drawable.pdf_half_star_4;
        } else if (rating == 3f) {
            image = R.drawable.pdf_star_4;
        } else if (rating == 3.5f) {
            image = R.drawable.pdf_half_star_5;
        } else if (rating == 4f) {
            image = R.drawable.pdf_star_5;
        } else if (rating == 4.5f) {
            image = R.drawable.pdf_half_star_6;
        } else if (rating == 5f) {
            image = R.drawable.pdf_star_6;
        }
        return image;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView mReceivedTV;
        private final TextView mNameTV;
        private final ImageView mRateIM;
        private final TextView mPriceTV;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mPriceTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
            mReceivedTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_received);
            mNameTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            mRateIM = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_rate);
        }
    }

}
```

My pdf model that gets the data from xml

```
public class PDFModel {

    private boolean isPending;
    private boolean isReceived;
    private String price;
    private String name;
    private float rating;

    public boolean isPending() {
        return isPending;
    }

    public void setPending(boolean pending) {
        isPending = pending;
    }

    public boolean isReceived() {
        return isReceived;
    }

    public void setReceived(boolean received) {
        isReceived = received;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public float getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(float rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    /**
     * Create dummy PDF model
     *
     * @return PDF Models
     */

    public static List<PDFModel> createDummyPdfModel() {
        PDFCreationUtils.filePath.clear();
        PDFCreationUtils.progressCount = 1;

        boolean isFirstReceivedItem = false;
        List<PDFModel> pdfModels = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 110; i++) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int price = rand.nextInt((1000 - 200) + 1) + 200;

            PDFModel model = new PDFModel();
            if (!isFirstReceivedItem) {
                model.setReceived(true);
                isFirstReceivedItem = true;
            } else {
                model.setReceived(false);
            }

            model.setPrice(String.valueOf(price) + String.valueOf(".0 Rs."));

            if (i % 4 == 0) {
                model.setName("Umesh Kumar " + i);
            } else {
                model.setName("Ram Kumar " + i);
            }
            model.setRating(i % 3);
            pdfModels.add(model);
        }

        return pdfModels;
    }
}
```

The flowing code is for crate pdf

this is pdfcrattionacivity.java

```
public class PdfCreationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private boolean IS_MANY_PDF_FILE;

    /**
     * This is identify to number of pdf file. If pdf model list size > sector so we have create many file. After that we have merge all pdf file into one pdf file
     */
    private int SECTOR = 100; // Default value for one pdf file.
    private int START;
    private int END = SECTOR;
    private int NO_OF_PDF_FILE = 1;
    private int NO_OF_FILE;
    private int LIST_SIZE;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    /**
     * Store all dummy PDF models
     */
    private List<PDFModel> pdfModels;
    private TextView btnPdfPath;


    /**
     * Share PDF file
     */
    private Button btnSharePdfFile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_creation);
        btnSharePdfFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_share_pdf);
        btnPdfPath = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_pdf_path);

        findViewById(R.id.btn_create_pdf).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                requestPermission();
            }
        });
        pdfModels = PDFModel.createDummyPdfModel();


        RecyclerView rvShowDemo = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_show_demo);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rvShowDemo.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        PdfCreateAdapter pdfRootAdapter = new PdfCreateAdapter();
        pdfRootAdapter.setListData(pdfModels);
        rvShowDemo.setAdapter(pdfRootAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 111 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            generatePdfReport();
        }
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 111);
        } else {
            generatePdfReport();
        }
    }


    /**
     * This is manage to all model
     */
    private void generatePdfReport() {


        // NO_OF_FILE : This is identify to one file or many file have to created

        LIST_SIZE = pdfModels.size();
        NO_OF_FILE = LIST_SIZE / SECTOR;
        if (LIST_SIZE % SECTOR != 0) {
            NO_OF_FILE++;
        }
        if (LIST_SIZE > SECTOR) {
            IS_MANY_PDF_FILE = true;
        } else {
            END = LIST_SIZE;
        }
        createPDFFile();
    }

    private void createProgressBarForPDFCreation(int maxProgress) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage(String.format(getString(R.string.msg_progress_pdf), String.valueOf(maxProgress)));
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setMax(maxProgress);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    private void createProgressBarForMergePDF() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_progress_merger_pdf));
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * This function call with recursion
     * This recursion depend on number of file (NO_OF_PDF_FILE)
     */
    private void createPDFFile() {

        // Find sub list for per pdf file data
        List<PDFModel> pdfDataList = pdfModels.subList(START, END);
        PdfBitmapCache.clearMemory();
        PdfBitmapCache.initBitmapCache(getApplicationContext());
        final PDFCreationUtils pdfCreationUtils = new PDFCreationUtils(PdfCreationActivity.this, pdfDataList, LIST_SIZE, NO_OF_PDF_FILE);
        if (NO_OF_PDF_FILE == 1) {
            createProgressBarForPDFCreation(PDFCreationUtils.TOTAL_PROGRESS_BAR);
        }
        pdfCreationUtils.createPDF(new PDFCreationUtils.PDFCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onProgress(final int i) {
                progressDialog.setProgress(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreateEveryPdfFile() {
                // Execute may pdf files and this is depend on NO_OF_FILE
                if (IS_MANY_PDF_FILE) {
                    NO_OF_PDF_FILE++;
                    if (NO_OF_FILE == NO_OF_PDF_FILE - 1) {

                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        createProgressBarForMergePDF();
                        pdfCreationUtils.downloadAndCombinePDFs();
                    } else {

                        // This is identify to manage sub list of current pdf model list data with START and END

                        START = END;
                        if (LIST_SIZE % SECTOR != 0) {
                            if (NO_OF_FILE == NO_OF_PDF_FILE) {
                                END = (START - SECTOR) + LIST_SIZE % SECTOR;
                            }
                        }
                        END = SECTOR + END;
                        createPDFFile();
                    }

                } else {
                    // Merge one pdf file when all file is downloaded
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    createProgressBarForMergePDF();
                    pdfCreationUtils.downloadAndCombinePDFs();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(final String filePath) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                if (filePath != null) {
                    btnPdfPath.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnPdfPath.setText("PDF path : " + filePath);
                    Toast.makeText(PdfCreationActivity.this, "pdf file " + filePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    btnSharePdfFile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnSharePdfFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            sharePdf(filePath);
                        }
                    });

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(PdfCreationActivity.this, "Error  " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }


    private void sharePdf(String fileName) {
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        File fileIn = new File(fileName);
        Uri u = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, fileIn);

        uris.add(u);
        emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.send_to)));
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_file), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

I am unable to get logic on how do i suppose to give command to print that generated PDF to printer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to connect to your printer and then send the `PDDocument` to the connected printer to print it. Something along the following lines should work.

```
public static PrintService choosePrinter() {
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    if(printJob.printDialog()) {
        return printJob.getPrintService();          
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

public static void printPDF(String fileName, PrintService printer)
        throws IOException, PrinterException {
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPrintService(printer);
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(fileName);
    doc.silentPrint(job);
}
```

Code referenced from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636622/pdfbox-how-to-print-pdf-with-specified-printer).